# A group theoretic question involving derivatives

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, derivatives, group-homomorphism

Let $f: (\mathbb{R},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R_0},.)$ be a homomorphism which is differentiable as a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Show that:

a) $f(x) > 0 \quad\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

b) $\exists a \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = e^{ax} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

For the first one, I think we can do the following:

$$f(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right) = \left(f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2 >0$$

Is this correct?

For the second one, can anyone give me a hint? I do not know how to implement the differentiability. I tried $$f'(x) = f'(x/2)$$ by using the chain rule on the expression above. I must somehow be able to show that $f'(x) = af(x)$, since then I can write $f(x) = e^{ax}$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy to see that $f(0)=1$ (identity to identity).

\begin{align*}
f^{'}(x) & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x) \cdot f(h)-f(x)}{h}\\
& = f(x)\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-1}{h}\\
& = f(x) \, f^{'}(0)
\end{align*}
Now let $f^{'}(0)=a$. Solve the differential equation
$$f^{'}(x) = af(x).$$

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Math_QED you are welcome.